# Why does sizeof(std::vector<int>) return 16 bytes, when it appears there are 20 bytes worth of member data?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, stl

As some opening info, I'm working with Visual Studio 2013 Community. I've noticed a mismatch between what appears to be inside a `std::vector`, and what is returned from sizeof, and I was wondering if anyone could shed any light on why this is how it is.

If I declare an empty vector:

```
std::vector<int> v;
```

then `sizeof(v)` is 16 bytes.

4 for the ptr to the first element. _MyFirst

4 for the ptr to just after the last element. _MyLast

4 for the capacity int.

4 for the size int.

Which makes sense.. except there is another member ptr in the vector class, to the end of the vector's capacity called _MyEnd.

So why does `sizeof(v)` not return 20 bytes?!

**EDIT:** Turns out some of my assertions were wrong :) The answers below pointed me in the right direction... just in case anyone comes across this in future and is puzzled.

The size of 16 was in debug mode, in release `sizeof` returns 12.
The 12 is the 3 pointers, `_MyFirst`, `_MyLast` and `_MyEnd`.

Comment: No, its not for production code, I'm just curious. I was doing some research into how std::containers allocate memory and how it all works under the hood, and i came across this.

Comment: `size` and one past the end ptr are redundant.

Comment: I think the key word is "appears". Please post the declaration, if you have the source code. Which I think is bundled with Visual Studio.

Comment: Not so helpful.. could you explain?

Comment: Visual Studio indeed "invents" members in the debugger. This happens for specific types where the internal representation doesn't match the logical value.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/d1reportSingleClassLayout` switch to your compiler arguments to see the layout of the class. STL explains the use of this switch in his [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-3-of-n). There was also a blog post about it from Microsoft SDET working on compiler, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that compiler flag is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rely on a `std::vector` being any particular size.  The size can even change between debug and release modes.  Typically a vector is [implemented with three pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422205/why-the-libc-stdvector-internally-keeps-three-pointers-instead-of-one-pointe) but it does have to.  In this case if you have a 64 bit system your vector could have 2 pointers.  One to the data and one to a struct that has the other information in it.  If you are going to need the size of the vector for something in your program then you should just use `sizeof(std::vector<type>)` and not use a "magic" number.

Comment: Yeah, upon a bit more inspection it is in fact just the 3 pointers. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no capacity and size member of a typical `std::vector` implementation.  It stores a pointer to the beginning, a pointer to one after the last element it's holding and a pointer just past the end of the allocated block.  From these 3 pointers it is able to get all the information it needs.

This is true for GCC as well as Visual Studio in Release.  In Debug `sizeof(std::vector<int>)` returns 32, probably to keep track of iterator invalidation but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, Guy, the fact there is an extra bit of data in debug pointed me in the right direction. It is in fact 3 ptrs, with an extra 4 bytes in debug for whatever thats for. When I ran this in release, it was 12.

Comment: @ChrisHaslehurst Glad I could help