# How does vectors in C++ use memory?

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> a(32768, 0);
    std::cout << "Size " << sizeof a << "\nCapacity " << a.capacity() << "\nElements " << a.size();
    return 0;
}
```

for this program im getting the output:

```
Size 24
Capacity 32768
Elements 32768
```

using valgrind i calculated heap usage which is:

132096 bytes

that is (32768 x 4 bytes) + 24 bytes

im interested in how are these 24 bytes used by vector a

Comment: Does for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422205/why-the-libc-stdvector-internally-keeps-three-pointers-instead-of-one-pointe answer your question? `that is (32768 x 4 bytes) + 24 bytes` that is... a coincidence that it's equal to that.

Comment: The 24 bytes are probably implementation dependent.
If you want to know more just open the <vector> header file :)
And you can also lookup "small vector optimization".

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you that explains it all :)

Comment: A vector allocates memory from the free store (usually the heap, or it is on all the platforms I currently work on).  It allocates more memory when it runs out of capacity.  It doesn't free extra capacity memory, unless requested.  My system maintains separate heaps for `malloc`, `new`, and `new[]` ... but that's an implementation detail, which helps shake out memory management bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As addressed in the comments by Kamil, a `std::vector` keeps track of three pointers internally. One pointer to the begin, one to end and one to the end of allocated memory (see [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422205/why-the-libc-stdvector-internally-keeps-three-pointers-instead-of-one-pointe)). Now, the size of a pointer should be 8 bytes on any 64-bit C/C++ compiler so, 3 * 8 bytes = 24 bytes (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models)).

Comment: This specific implementation is not required by the standard, just popular.